# Missing iTextSharp DTD

Tags: itext

I was reading the [iTextSharp sample for parsing XML](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/ch07.html) and they mention a DTD, which should be located at the following location: http://www.lowagie.com/iText/itext.dtd

Unfortunately, it appears as though the location of the DTD has changed. Does anybody know where I can find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this:

[www.ujihara.jp/iTextdotNET/examples/files/itext.dtd](http://www.ujihara.jp/iTextdotNET/examples/files/itext.dtd)

I have no idea if it be suitable for your needs.

Comment: I think that's the one. Thank you very much!